# Why is Ubuntu 22.04 shutting down unexpectedly?

Tags: shutdown, temperature, 22.04, cpufreq

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and my Dell laptop started shutting down unexpectedly. It seems like my CPUs are spiking to 100%, then shutting down.

In many cases I can’t do the most simple task, like opening VS Code, in others it shuts down seconds after I log in. Sometimes I can see an error saying it shut down due to temperature, but the machine is always very cool to the touch.

This never happened on Ubuntu 20.04.

Laptop Specs:

- Dell Inc. Inspiron 15 3510
- 16 GB Memory
- CPU: Intel® Pentium(R) Silver N5030 CPU @ 1.10GHz × 4
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 605 (GLK 3)
- Disk: 512 GB
- Roughly 3 months old.

Here are some useful logs:

- Hardware Logs:

  ```
  16:07:45 kernel: thermal thermal_zone0: acpitz: critical temperature reached, shutting down
  16:07:22 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
  16:07:21 kernel: usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:6d1a)
  16:07:20 kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
  16:07:20 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0 wlo2: renamed from wlan0
  16:07:20 kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:0f.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
  16:07:20 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
  16:07:20 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
  16:07:20 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
  16:07:20 kernel: hid-multitouch 0018:27C6:0D43.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DELL0AAF:00 27C6:0D43] on i2c-DELL0AAF:00
  16:07:20 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: base HW address: 20:1e:88:4e:c4:ce
  16:07:20 kernel: thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
  16:07:20 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
  16:07:20 kernel: dell-smbios A80593CE-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492: WMI SMBIOS userspace interface not supported(0), try upgrading to a newer BIOS
  16:07:20 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: loaded firmware version 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
  16:07:19 kernel: ee1004 1-0050: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
  16:07:19 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
  16:07:19 kernel: intel-hid INT33D5:00: platform supports 5 button array
  16:07:19 kernel: evdi evdi.3: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
  16:07:19 kernel: hid-generic 0003:1532:009C.0006: input,hiddev1,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 X HyperSpeed] on usb-0000:00:15.0-1/input3
  16:07:19 kernel: usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
  16:07:19 kernel: hid-generic 0018:27C6:0D43.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DELL0AAF:00 27C6:0D43] on i2c-DELL0AAF:00
  16:07:19 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
  16:07:19 kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SSD SATA3 512GB  0A0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
  16:07:19 kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
  16:07:19 kernel: idma64 idma64.7: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
  16:07:19 kernel: i2c i2c-1: Successfully instantiated SPD at 0x50
  16:07:19 kernel: idma64 idma64.2: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
  16:07:19 kernel: i2c i2c-1: 1/1 memory slots populated (from DMI)
  16:07:19 kernel: scsi host1: ahci
  16:07:19 kernel: ahci 0000:00:12.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm clo only pmp pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
  16:07:19 kernel: hub 2-0:1.0: 7 ports detected
  16:07:19 kernel: usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:15.0
  16:07:19 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:15.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
  16:07:19 kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 9 ports detected
  16:07:19 kernel: usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:15.0
  16:07:19 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:15.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000000009810
  16:07:19 kernel: ahci 0000:00:12.0: version 3.0
  16:07:19 kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.1: SMBus using PCI interrupt
  16:07:19 kernel: idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
  16:07:19 kernel: acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
  16:07:19 kernel: wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQBC data block query control method not found
  16:07:19 kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Detected 0 cards
  16:07:19 kernel: rtc_cmos 00:04: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
  16:07:19 kernel: thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
  16:07:19 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:14.1: PME: Signaling with IRQ 124
  16:07:19 kernel: pci_bus 0000:00: resource 19 [mem 0xfed80000-0xfedbffff window]
  16:07:19 kernel: pci 0000:00:14.1: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
  16:07:19 kernel: system 00:01: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfeefffff] could not be reserved
  16:07:19 kernel: pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
  16:07:19 kernel: pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xfed80000-0xfedbffff window]
  ```
- Important logs:

  ```
  16:07:45 canonical-livep: daemon shutting down
  16:07:45 gdm3: Gdm: Failed to contact accountsservice: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Accounts: Transaction for accounts-daemon.service/start is destructive (dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:12.0\x2data\x2d1.0\x2dpart5.swap has 'stop' job queued, but 'start' is included in transaction).
  16:07:45 systemd-logind: Failed to start autovt@tty2.service: Transaction for getty@tty2.service/start is destructive (poweroff.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
  16:07:45 kernel: reboot: HARDWARE PROTECTION shutdown (Temperature too high)
  16:07:45 kernel: thermal thermal_zone0: acpitz: critical temperature reached, shutting down
  16:07:40 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
  16:07:38 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
  16:07:22 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/eee7feecac2a487db8eed9aef9ab1d79/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
  16:07:22 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  16:07:19 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
  ```

Comment: Well, what do your logs say? Keep in mind that Ubuntu-caused shutdown are always logged so you can discover the reason. If nothing is logged, then you have a hardware problem that is coincidentally occuring after the release-upgrade. Warnings about temperature fall under hardware (not Ubuntu) faults.

Comment: First, make sure all your sensors are working. Install `lm-sensors` package by running the following commands: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install lm-sensors` Then, run the following command to detect your sensors (select `y` or `yes` when prompted): `sudo sensors-detect`

Comment: The machine being "cool to the touch" doesn't mean the processor hasn't exceeded its maximum temperature. That can all happen on a millisecond time scale. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373633/how-to-troubleshoot-cpu-hw-crash-in-ubuntu-18-04/1373784#1373784), where I have measured a processor temperature increase rate of 800 degrees per second (which obviously would slow down as it gets higher).

Comment: @user535733 I have just added the logs.

Comment: @mchid I installed and ran the package. There was a lot of prompts for probing (All of which I said yes to). This was the result:

```Driver 'coretemp':
  * Chip 'Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)
```

Comment: @mchid I have just added the `Hardware` and `important` logs in code blocks as requested. I can add the `systems` ; `applications` or `all` logs too if need be.

Comment: How's your Fan? Rotating, unblocked? How dusty is the inside of the computer (dust is an insulator - keeps the heat in)?

Comment: @waltinator The fan is quiet. I used compressed air to remove any dust if there was any. PC is roughly 3 months old. I have added PC Specs to the question.

Comment: Please be precise with details; 20 & 22 are different Ubuntu products to 20.04 & 22.04; ie. the *year* format used for *snap* only releases where as the *year.month* format for *deb* based products that can also use *snap* packages. Your question & tag mixes two different products that require a re-install & don't upgrade (if a 20 upgrades to 22 no user packages will change; unlike when a 20.04 upgrades to 22.04 which requires the whole system to upgrade - they differ)

Comment: @guiverc I believe I was fairly explicit in stating that I am using Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish), **not** ubuntu 20. I recently upgraded, and then started experiencing these issues.

Comment: I suggest a thermal monitoring/throttling daemon such as thermald (which might already be running, don't know), with a low enough trip point to prevent temperature overshoot to the shutdown point. Your processor TDP (Thermal design Power) is very low.

Comment: @RafaelZasas you state Ubuntu 22 a number of times, implying a *snap* only product of Ubuntu; Ubuntu Core 22 is based on 22.04 but is a different product; with the 22 or *year* format highlighting the different product when compared to *year.month* format used for *deb* based products of Ubuntu.  22 is explicitly different to 22.04, just as 20 is explicitly different to 20.04.

Comment: Same problem here, could be relatd with this bug?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1968907

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the coretemp module at an earlier stage:

```
 printf "# BUGFIX: pre load coretemp to fix Laptop Thermal Shutdown Bug\ncoretemp\n" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/bugfix-coretemp.conf
```

Reboot and see if the problem gets fixed.