# How to turn off password when start the machine?

Tags: 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS without graphics, only with command line. I need to run scripts after reboot (nodejs). Now after reboot at first I need to log into my user account by ssh and enter password, and only then my scripts start automatically.

Is it possible not to ask for a password when the machine turns on and to log into my user automatically after reboot?

Comment: Disabling password might help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password .

Comment: Consider having your post-boot scripts run automatically as root and as a systemd service. There is an example "how to" as an added EDIT to an old answer to another question, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373633/how-to-troubleshoot-cpu-hw-crash-in-ubuntu-18-04/1373784#1373784), search for "EDIT: To make the TCC offset method setup automatically on boot, post-boot service is suggested."

Comment: 2nd line: If you want passwordless ssh check out how public and private keys work BUT I agree woth @DougSmythies systemd service is the way to go. Those get started during a boot and can be told to start, or stop based on events. The 2nd and 3rd line are 2 different things: the 3rd is probably not possible anymore but you need to edit "getty" configuration to automatically log into tty1. Don't though. systemd services is far easier and a lot more portable.

Comment: The best solution would be to have password when I connect by ssh, but no password to log in by my user account when the machine starts: I send "reboot", the machine reboots, fully loads the OS and then (what is already implemented) runs my scripts.