# Ubuntu 22.04 - CPU constantly running too hot at 90°C

Tags: 22.04, intel, cpu, temperature, cpufreq

the output of sensors is constantly looking something like this with regular spikes over 90°C or 95°C for multiple seconds.
This does not seem healthy for the life of the CPU.

I am using a ThinkBook 16 G4+ IAP with an i7-12700H

Is there a way I can tell my system that I would prefer a temperature under 85 even when that means throttling?

sensors output:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +88.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +88.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 16:       +76.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 20:       +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 24:       +62.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 25:       +62.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 26:       +62.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 27:       +63.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 28:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 29:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 30:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 31:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I also saw some cores seem to have a higher max. freq. and wondered if that might have something to do with it

```
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ      MHZ
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4600,0000 400,0000  628.005
  1    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4600,0000 400,0000 2700.000
  2    0      0    1 4:4:1:0          yes 4600,0000 400,0000 2700.000
  3    0      0    1 4:4:1:0          yes 4600,0000 400,0000 2700.000
  4    0      0    2 8:8:2:0          yes 4700,0000 400,0000 4692.256
  5    0      0    2 8:8:2:0          yes 4700,0000 400,0000 2700.000
  6    0      0    3 12:12:3:0        yes 4700,0000 400,0000 2189.011
  7    0      0    3 12:12:3:0        yes 4700,0000 400,0000 2700.000
  8    0      0    4 16:16:4:0        yes 4600,0000 400,0000  400.227
  9    0      0    4 16:16:4:0        yes 4600,0000 400,0000 2700.000
 10    0      0    5 20:20:5:0        yes 4600,0000 400,0000 2700.000
 11    0      0    5 20:20:5:0        yes 4600,0000 400,0000 1565.576
 12    0      0    6 24:24:6:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 1641.534
 13    0      0    7 25:25:6:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 2700.000
 14    0      0    8 26:26:6:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 1337.855
 15    0      0    9 27:27:6:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 2700.000
 16    0      0   10 28:28:7:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 1751.545
 17    0      0   11 29:29:7:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 2700.000
 18    0      0   12 30:30:7:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 2700.000
 19    0      0   13 31:31:7:0        yes 3500,0000 400,0000 1929.793
```

Comment: Your 12th generation Intel processor will have both performance cores and efficient cores, with the performance cores able to go to higher frequencies. And yes, the temperature (and power) verses frequency curve can be rather steep at the highest frequencies. You might be running some thermal throttling daemon already and merely need to reduce the trip point temperature. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373633/how-to-troubleshoot-cpu-hw-crash-in-ubuntu-18-04/1373784#1373784) for an old answer about this. Your processor should be able to do TCC Offset thermal throttling.

Comment: Bios update? The release note say something about "... thermal ...".

Comment: I checked on Windows and the BIOS is already the newest version sadly. @Marco