# why does Ubuntu throttle my CPU 9° sooner than what crit says?

Tags: intel, cpu, temperature

When stress testing with mprime small FFTs the CPU temperatures should reach at least 95°C, but they appear to get throttled at approx 89°C even though sensors correctly report that the "crit" value is 98°C which is equal to my BIOS throttling threshold temperature setting.

It works fine in windows 11 with prime95: the cpu is only throttled when it reaches 98°C and the fans ramp up audibly more in windows because of the higher temperature. I don't think it's the power limit or the current limit as the power draw is  way below the limit (and again it works fine in windows).

I checked the many other questions related to thermal throttling, but didn't find an answer.

- Ubuntu desktop 22.04.3 fresh install
- CPU: Intel i7-14700K (only 4 P-cores enabled) I think this was also happening with a i7-13700K
- MB: PRO Z790-P WIFI DDR4 (bios 7E06v18)
- power limit PL1 = PL2: 300W
- power draw on EPS cable: 180W
- reported power draw in software: 140W

Comment: The method of investigation is processor dependant. Please add some system information to your question.: Processor make and model; motherboard make; What is the power limit and what is the actual power? mprime, small FFTs is the best stress test I know of, and when it starts I have measured extremely fast processor temperature increases, [800 degrees per second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373633/how-to-troubleshoot-cpu-hw-crash-in-ubuntu-18-04/1373784#1373784). Much faster than fans reaction time.

Comment: Do you know about, and use, turbostat (linux tools common package, I think)? I would suggest it as the best feedback tool as to what is going on. I would suggest this command: `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 10` and change to shorter intervals as required. However, I don't currently have an answer to your question.

Comment: What do you get for `grep . /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.?/hwmon/hwmon?/temp*`? Is thermald running? (`sudo systemctl status thermald`) Do you have any TCC Offset? (The startup spew of stuff with turbostat will contain that information, perhaps add it to the question).

Comment: @DougSmythies I don't know, I just installed ubuntu fresh and did almost no configuring. These are the outputs from the commands you listed: https://pastebin.com/VASKxHxE
I don't see any TCC offset anywhere

Comment: I don't see the TCC offset either. Example: `cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x37641422 (45 C) (100 default - 55 offset)`. Your version of turbostat, `turbostat version 2022.10.04`, should have it, as your processor is so new (maybe to new). Your [tempX_max](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.2/hwmon/coretemp.html) are all set to 78 degrees C, and so throttling should be engaged above that. I am not sure what thermald will do when `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` is missing. Leave turbostat always running so you can observe things.

Comment: Your `thermald` is using the `--adaptive` option. [Info about DPTF](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/thermal/intel_dptf.html) .

Comment: @DougSmythies why is it set to 78 and how can I change it?

Comment: It seems to be critical - 20 degrees, because mine is 80, and critical = 100. As you can see it is a read only thing. I don't know how to change it.