# Keep CPU under a certain temperature

Tags: cpu, temperature

Distro & Computer: Ubuntu 23.10, but I am willing to switch distros. Acer ultralight laptop with AMD 7735U processor.

Is there a way to throttle the CPU based on temperature? Whenever the computer runs anything processor intensive for more than a few seconds, the computer heats up to the point where it is uncomfortable to use. Looking at the PSensor graph, it looks like the machine is hardware thermal throttled at 95C, but I'd love to be able to set it much later at like 70C or 75C.

Thank for any help!

Comment: Have you tried thermald?: https://askubuntu.com/q/1400361/1004020

Comment: I apologize for not seeing your response earlier. I didn't get a notification and assumed that no one answered. I will look into setting up thermald. Thank you for the advice!